gcc -O3 diagnostic warning: '<U ea0>' is used uninitialized - UB, bug or "name mangling"?
While answering this question I toyed with an idea of sneaking past the C constraint of not casting a float into a pointer and came up with this nasty bit of exotic, artificial code:
(Obviously we shouldn't write real product code like this - please note the "language-lawyer" tag.)
#include <stdio.h>

void get_value (void* data)
{
    printf("Value %f \r\n", *(float*)&(int){(int)data});
}


int main(void) {
    float di = 10.10f;

    get_value( (void*) ((union cheeky{int i; float f;}){.f=di}.i) ); 
    return 0;
}

As far as I can tell this is valid C. The union in main() ought to mean that strict aliasing  doesn't apply, although I'm not sure what the "effective type" is here, as the object has multiple representations. Initializing another int with the contents of that union by casting to void* in between sure is fishy but at least the correct result gets printed.
Of course the integer to pointer conversion is implementation-defined, as are the sizes of int and float, and gcc complains accordingly as it should. And obviously there might be UB in case the pointer is misaligned or a trap representation etc.
However, when I added optimization, I got this real strange diagnostic.
gcc -std=c2x -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -O3
<source>:5:29: warning: '<U ea0>' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
    5 |     printf("Value %f \r\n", *(float*)&(int){(int)data});
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:5:44: note: '({anonymous})' declared here
    5 |     printf("Value %f \r\n", *(float*)&(int){(int)data});
      |                                            ^

So this is referring to the compound literal inside the function. Which is clearly initialized, right there, by the cast from void*. This warning only pops up under the combination of -O3 and using gcc 11 or later. Older gcc does not give the warning and neither does clang.
I also seem to get a different cryptic "hex code" <U ea0> etc depending on gcc version but it is probably(?) just because I'm getting a different build each time in Compiler Explorer.
Questions:

Is there any undefined behavior here which I didn't spot or is this code just implementation-defined?
Is this intentional and some manner of internal "name mangling" of anonymous compound literals? If so why does it only appear under -O3? I tried __attribute__((noinline)) but it makes no difference.
Or is this a diagnostics bug in gcc?


Edit

I noted that fixing the supposed strict aliasing violation inside the function makes the warning go away:
printf("Value %f \r\n", (union cheeky{int i; float f;}){.i=(int)data}.f);


If replacing the compound literal version with a named variable, I get another flavour of the same diagnostic:
__attribute__((noinline)) static void get_value (void* data)
{
    int i = (puts("Uninitialized, my old shoes"), (int)data);
    float f = *(float*) &i;
    printf("Value %f \r\n", f );
}

gives:
<source>: In function 'get_value':
<source>:5:51: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
    5 |     int i = (puts("Uninitialized, my old shoes"), (int)data);
      |                                                   ^
<source>:6:16: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    6 |     float f = *(float*) &i;
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>: In function 'get_value':
<source>:6:11: warning: 'i' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
    6 |     float f = *(float*) &i;
      |           ^
<source>:5:9: note: 'i' declared here
    5 |     int i = (puts("Uninitialized, my old shoes"), (int)data);
      |         ^

The 2 first warnings are correct and expected. The 3rd is nonsense. However, the 3rd one doesn't appear with gcc 11 -O3 but with gcc 12 -O3 or later.
The output is as expected (if you can expect anything with explicit UB, that is):
Uninitialized, my old shoes
Value 10.100000 




I believe it is a gcc error. Wrong scope and lifetime calculations. https://godbolt.org/z/xddjas55v


UB  in the code not related to the issue.


BTW removing the obvious error in the code sorts out the warning https://godbolt.org/z/4x6aj788v

@gulpr The more I think of it the more it looks like strict aliasing UB because the compound literal in the function is a new variable. Although one would preferably not have the compiler rambling about irrelevant things, UB or not. "dereferencing type-punned pointer..." is a sensible warning, the one I got is not.

While tinkering, I tried int foo(void) { return * (int *) &(short){3}; }, and one of the messages was “note: object '' of size 2”, revealing that <U cf0> is the compiler’s “name” for the compound literal object. (That is implicit in previous messages but clearer here.)

I also noted that if I use the same type punning trick in the function, the warning goes away: printf("Value %f \r\n", (union cheeky{int i; float f;}){.i=(int)data}.f);. Supposedly the first version had a strict aliasing violation and this type pun version does not.

I would guess this is something with aliasing diagnostics that was changed in the latter versions. As in "if you are doing strict aliasing violations, I'm going to assume really strange things not only in the executable but during compilation as well".

Adding -fno-strict-aliasing makes the warning go away, so it looks like it's being viewed as a strict aliasing violation.

The Standard would characterize your program as "non-portable or erroneous", without imposing any judgment whether it is non-portable but correct (and "valid") C, or whether it is erroneous (and/or "invalid.  The use of a union seems a bit of a red herring.
Your code as written poses at least three portability issues that I can see, the first two of which you acknowledge:

While the Standard does syntactically allow pointers to be converted to integers and vice versa, it says very little about the results of such conversions.

There is no guarantee that objects of type float and int have compatible sizes and alignment requirements.

The Standard deliberately allows implementations to assume that storage of any particular type will only be accessed via lvalues of that particular type in cases where such assumption would allow an implementation to process customers' programs more usefully.  When the Standard was written, nobody cared about whether it would allow compilers to abuse such assumptions in situations where they obviously didn't apply and would make an implementation less useful, because nobody seeking to sell compilers would have done so.  Here, clang is deciding that there's no way an object accessed via float* object could have received a value as a result of initializing an int object.


According to the published Rationale, the authors of the Standard recognized that it would be possible for someone to craft an implementation that was conforming but would nonetheless "succeed at being useless".  In almost all cases, the question of whether a particular implementation processes a particular program usefully is a "quality of implementation" issue outside the Standard's jurisdiction.  Contrary to what some compiler writers or their apologists claim, the Standard expressly did not wish to demean useful programs that happen not to be portable (especially, presumably, in cases where they perform a task more efficiently than would be possible in portable code), and views as "conforming" any program that is accepted by at least one C implementation somewhere in the universe.
Clang is squawking because its authors would rather use the Standard to justify an inability to process constructs such as yours usefully, than behave in useful fashion.
